# MySQL Grouping Issue

Tags: php, sql

I would like to show data group by Continent.

I have the following table:

```
Table: Score

RegionID  | RegionName  | Continent  | Score
----------+-------------+------------+-------
A001      | Hong Kong   | Asia       | 97
A002      | Macau       | Asia       | 94
A003      | Taiwan      | Asia       | 95
A004      | Seoul       | Asia       | 96
A005      | Tokyo       | Asia       | 95
A006      | Osaka       | Asia       | 93
E001      | London      | Europe     | 88
A007      | Beijing     | Asia       | 83
E002      | Paris       | Europe     | 89
U001      | New York    | N. America | 91
U002      | Las Vegas   | N. America | 90
T001      | Sydney      | Australia  | 98
```

Expected Output:

```
Asia:
-----------------------------------------
97 - Hong Kong
94 - Macau

...

N. America
-----------------------------------------
91 - New York
90 - Las Vegas
```

Now I have to separate the SQL command to output this.

I need a faster solution than

```
SELECT * FROM Score WHERE Continent='Asia'
SELECT * FROM Score WHERE Continent='N. America'
```

Comment: One single ordered query and php code for presentation. If you'll wait 20mins I'll show you code in answer.

Comment: @notulysses Grouping the continents and done by PHP may solve my issue. Can you provide more details or you can post it in answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select everything in one query:

```
SELECT * FROM Score WHERE Continent IN ('Asia', 'N. America');
```

Then, in `PHP`, you would do as `notulyssess` suggested and with the result set do:

```
$data[$row['continent']][] = $row;
```

Finnally, you would loop through your `$data` array as such:

```
for($data as $continent => $entries){
    echo '<b>' . $continent . '</b><br />-----------------------------------------<br />';
    for($entries as $e){
        echo $e['score'] . ' - ' . $e['region_name'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This direction may solve my problem. I will take a look.

Answer (score 3):

That's not `GROUPED` data from database. That's simply a sorted list and then you use your programming language (PHP) to show the grouping.

```
SELECT * FROM Score ORDER BY Continent
```

Now when you get that result you have to use PHP to show each new continent in a new line and then show its entries. Since you need all the rows, doing that grouping with database only will be an overkill. And you have to create your continent headers in PHP anyway.

Comment: I am not caring about the sorting issue but it will be very complicated if I only use Address, Region and Score.

Comment: This will return the data sorted and you will be able to do looping and accessing it easily.

Comment: @AkiEru If you only want certain continents, you can add a OR on your single query, so you'd use: `SELECT * FROM Score WHERE Continent='Asia' OR Continent='N. America' ORDER BY Continent`. If it is slow, you might need to add an index on the `Continent` column. That's a whole other subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Score WHERE Continent='Asia' limit 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM Score WHERE Continent='N. America' limit 2
```

Hope this help you..

Comment: I am just skipped the other results, not limiting the result.

Comment: No need for UNION since no duplicates are supposed to be removed. Do UNION ALL instead!

Answer (score 0):

For offered solution the query has to be:

```
SELECT * FROM Score ORDER BY Continent
```

And the php presentation will be:

```
<?php

// I've entered the sample data as a array - you'll got it the same after the query.
// I've qvoid the last column from your sample data, because it isn't important for my presentation
$dat=array(
0=>array('RegionID'=>'A001','RegionName'=>'Hong Kong','Continent'=>'Asia'),
1=>array('RegionID'=>'A002','RegionName'=>'Macau','Continent'=>'Asia'),
2=>array('RegionID'=>'A003','RegionName'=>'Taiwan','Continent'=>'Asia'),
3=>array('RegionID'=>'A004','RegionName'=>'Seoul','Continent'=>'Asia'),
4=>array('RegionID'=>'A005','RegionName'=>'Tokyo','Continent'=>'Asia'),
5=>array('RegionID'=>'A006','RegionName'=>'Osaka','Continent'=>'Asia'),
6=>array('RegionID'=>'A007','RegionName'=>'Beijing','Continent'=>'Asia'),
7=>array('RegionID'=>'E001','RegionName'=>'London','Continent'=>'Europe'),
8=>array('RegionID'=>'E002','RegionName'=>'Paris','Continent'=>'Europe'),
9=>array('RegionID'=>'U001','RegionName'=>'New York','Continent'=>'N. America'),
10=>array('RegionID'=>'U002','RegionName'=>'Las Vegas','Continent'=>'N. America'),
11=>array('RegionID'=>'T001','RegionName'=>'Sydney','Continent'=>'Australia'),
);

// Maincode
$sbuf='';
foreach($dat as $da){
    if($da['Continent']!=$sbuff){
        "<br/>".echo $da['Continent']."<br/>-----------------------------------------<br/>";
    }
    echo $da['RegionName']."<br/>";
    $sbuff=$da['Continent'];
}
?>
```